# Are there any terminals that have fully customizable keybinds?

Tags: terminal

Reason being is that I use emacs-nox, meaning the text-editor program runs inside the terminal.

And many of my binds conflict with the terminal keybinds (such as <kbd>Ctrl+i</kbd>)


So are there any terminals out there that allow for any given command signal to be *turned off*.

Answer (score 0):

Yes indeed there is.

Most definitely.

xterm